# Launch program in python with a different environment

Tags: python, subprocess, system, environment

I have an initial python script for which I set a specific environment (LD_LIBRARY_PATH, ...).
In this script, I want to call an other program which also requires a specific environment which is not compatible with the first one.
I tried os.system and subprocess commands but it looks as if, that when launching these commands, both of them keep the initial environment.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you could provide us with a [minimum reproducible example(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), if would help us debug this issue and understand it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`subprocess.Popen()` accepts an `env` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#//apple_ref/Class/subprocess.Popen) that you can use, e.g. to augment the current environment with an additional thing,

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(..., env={**os.environ, 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/something/'})
```

or to wholesale replace it,

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(..., env={'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/something/'})
```